# how we can write wsdl.xml or wsi.xml in Magento 2.2.5?

Tags: sales-order, magento-2.2.5

In magento 1.9.3.9, we have added the new fields in `wsdl.xml` and `wsi.xml`. then that is looking like below

[image](http://prntscr.com/kyzi6w).

How can I write the above code in magento 2.2.5?